# Java: When to use CertPathValidator vs TrustManager for verifying certificates?

Tags: java, cryptography

Seems like both classes can be used to verify certificates. And CertPathValidator has support for CRLs. How do I determine when to use each for verifying an entity certificate?

Comment: Mind elucidating on why they are not the same? Cursory reading indicates that both classes can be used to validate certificate chains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X509TrustManager` is used to check if a certificate is considered as trusted.
`CertPathValidator` is used to check if a chain of certificate is valid (i.e. you can indeed form a certification path out of the certificates, from subject to issuer all the way up to the root)

**Update after comments**
Valid is not a superset or subset of trusted.This is your misunderstanding.Valid certificate means that the certificate has the proper extensions, has not expired or been revoked.Valid chain is that each certificate in the chain is valid an each certificate in the chain forms a valid path.Now whether the certificates are considered trusted is a different story.They may indeed be valid in the way described but are not part of the trusted certificates

Comment: Assuming that the path was constructed from trusted certs, then does CertPathValidator cover the functionality of X509TrustManager? Will it also check for expiration and keyusage issues?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between 'valid' and 'trusted'?

Comment: My understanding was that valid is a superset of trusted. Valid means trusted and it has not been revoked. Care to clarify?

Comment: @zer0stimulus Then your understanding is completely back to front. A certificate is valid if its signature matches its content and it is within its not-before/not-after dates. A signature is trusted if (a) it is valid and (b) it is present in your truststore.